# How to pass multiple values in googleapiclient.discover.build()

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to filter the search query here where if I search for anything it should come from only certain site. I am defining in the "siteSearch" parameter. If I pass single value "yelp.com", i am getting proper response, If i pass multiple values in the same parametor I am getting empty response. Any suggestions

```
def search_restaurant(query):
    result_links = []

    api_key = 
    search_engine_id = 

    service = build('customsearch', 'v1', developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(
        q=query,
        cx=search_engine_id,
        num=3,
        siteSearch=["yelp.com", "tripadvisor.com", "usmenuguide.com"]
    ).execute()
    print(res)
    if 'items' in res:
        for item in res['items']:
            result_links.append(item['link'])

    return result_links
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify more than one site within the [Programmable Search Engine](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/controlpanel/all) by defining your multiple sites on the Sites to Search options like so:

[image]

Reference:
https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/12397162